# Display a xml file in a html text area

Tags: html, xml

I want to display the contents of a xml in a textarea along with syntax coloring for attributes is that possible?

Comment: Refer this link...http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=96295

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with out-of-the-box XHTML/HTML TextArea element.

You can use some client-side processing in order to color XML, but, anyway, in order to embed such XML, you should encode it with HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot change the color or style of individual words within a textarea, because you can't nest DOM nodes within a textarea.

```
<div><span class="a">I can</span> <span class="b">style this text</span></div>

<textarea>I can't style this text</textarea>
```